# Not getting anything with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I'd like to get a value from some lines of a code and that's my current code:

```
$body = "<td class='tam12'><img src='/assets/img/banderas/es.png' width='30' height='20' /></td><td class='tam12'>2017-05-22</td><td class='tam12'><img src='/assets/img/servidores/streamplay.jpg' width='80' height='25' style='border-radius:4px;' /></td><td><a class='capitulo2' href='anonim.php?id=4936681&e=' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' alt=''>Ver online</a>";
$patternopenload = "#<img src='/assets/img/banderas/es.png' width='[^']*' height='[^']*' /></td><td class='tam12'>[^']*</td><td class='tam12'><img src='/assets/img/servidores/streamplay.jpg' width='[^']*' height='[^']*' style='[^']* /></td><td><a class='[^']*' href='(.*?)' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' alt=''>Ver online</a></td>";
preg_match($patternopenload, $body, $primero);
echo $primero[1];
```

But i'm not getting anything. I don't understand why i've revised it at least fifty times, if someone could help me i'd be very grateful

Comment: First of all, don't parse HTML with regex.  You missed the end delimiter in your regex (ie. `#`). `...Ver online</a></td>#";`

Comment: @Toto yes i noticed it after sending the post, i fixed it but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [delimeters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) / in regex pattern:

preg_match requires you to do something like this

```
preg_match('/{pattern}/', $subject);
```

Assuming you want to get href link so regex should be

```
$patternopenload = "/<a class='capitulo2' href='(.+)' rel='.+' target='.+'/";
```

Return **anonim.php?id=4936681&e=**

Comment: Yes it worked but I must include in the pattern the two `<img>` cause I need them for a future preg_match_all that get the href from just the `<td>` that just have those imgs

Comment: and if i add them it doesn't work again

Comment: So you want to get the link and the image url?